# Двойная пагинация в одном swiper container

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper

Двойная пагинация разных типов в одном контейнере.

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: Используйте больше заимствованных слов в одному лишь вам понятном значении =) Давайте заменим часть американизмов в вашем предложение и попробуем вместе его понять? `необходимо сделать две страницы в одном контейнере причем разных типов числовой и пуля.` Я отказываюсь это понимать адекватно =) пишите по русски.

Comment: pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
      }
Я про это говорил. Также необходим второй pagination type: 'fraction'

Comment: Сильно понятнее не стало. Приведите код, покажите наглядно, что вы хотите и что не получается.

Comment: <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
не знаю, как добавить еще один swiper-pagination в контейнер. Помимо точек, надо еще сделать нумерацию слайдов, 1/6 к примеру.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос а не в комментарий. Важд=ные замечания так же добавляйте в вопрос. Так не придется бегать в комменты. А те кто первый раз открыл вопрос и вовсе не будет знать что есть какая-то инфа важная в комментах.  Вопрос можно редактировать нажав на кнопку  "править" под Вашим вопросом.

Comment: Без ваших же комментариев совершенно непонятно что именно и с чем вы хотите сделать. Чтобы вопрос и ответ на него представлял ценность для сообщества, подробнее опишите с чем мы имеем дело (из комментариев и тега понятно, что это библиотека для "Swiper") и какую-то разметку. Все подробности следует добавить в сам текст вопроса и заголовок.

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека "Swiper" предлагает помимо режимов `bullets` и `fraction` еще и `custom`, вот туда и следует копать. На сайте библиотеки есть вполне вменяемая [демка](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/070-pagination-custom.html), которая рассказывает как пользоваться кастомной пагинацией, привожу ее код:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination', // "String with CSS selector or HTML element of the container with pagination" - цитата из документации, обратие внимание
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    },
  },
});
```

Так вы сможете сделать свою первую пагинацию, которая должна быть с номерами.

Вторую же, судя по всему, придется делать почти руками: воспользуйтесь [API Swiper'а](https://swiperjs.com/api/#methods), например методом `mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks)` повесив его на каждый свой буллет. Количество слайдов можете тоже посчитать при помощи API `mySwiper.slides.length`.

Пробуйте.

UPD
[Вот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58431888/3076663), который раскрывает то, что я имел ввиду (хотя код весьма запутанный, как по мне, но всё же).

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет, все по делу ответил. Буду разбираться.